# Calculate Sub Query Column Based On Calculated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table ScheduleRotationDetail that contains these as columns:

```
ScheduleRotationID  ScheduleID  Ordinal Duration
379                 61          1       1
379                 379         2       20
379                 512         3       1
379                 89          4       20
```

I have a query that goes like this in order to get the day of the year each schedule is supposed to start on:

```
SELECT ScheduleID, Ordinal, Duration,
                ,Duration * 7 AS DurationDays
                ,( SELECT ( ISNULL( SUM(ISNULL( Duration, 0 )), 0 ) - 1 ) * 7 
                   FROM ScheduleRotationDetail WHERE ScheduleRotationID = srd.ScheduleRotationID
                       AND Ordinal <= srd.Ordinal ) AS StartDay
FROM ScheduleRotationDetail srd 
WHERE srd.ScheduleRotationID = 379
```

That outputs this as the result set:

```
ScheduleID  Ordinal   Duration  DurationDays    StartDay
61          1         1           7             0
379         2         20          140           140
512         3         1           7             147
89          4         20          140           287
```

Yet what I need the start day column values to be are:

```
0
7
147
154
```

I have tried CTEs but can't get it to work so I've come to here for advice.

Comment: Please show us your data and table definitions (the latter as one-liners is fine).  Also, I don't see CTE being used in the above query.

Comment: Added more information above. Just said I tried it with a CTE and couldn't get it to work so I left it as the sub query way.

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen said, we need the sample data and table structures, also a clearer description of what the calculation for `StartDay` is supposed to be doing would help.

Comment: Added more information. Please let me know if you need more or if it's still a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2012+, you can do:

```
SELECT ScheduleID, Ordinal, Duration,
       SUM(Duration*7) OVER (ORDER BY Ordinal) - Duration*7 as StartDate
FROM ScheduleRotationDetail srd ;
```

In earlier versions, you can use `APPLY` for this purpose (or a correlated subquery).

Comment: Multiply your query by seven and it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @HongSmythe . . . Ah, I see.